# Apache virtualHost without wildcard?

Tags: apache2

I've never seen `VirtualHost` config like this:

```
<VirtualHost my.com:443>
```

Is it possible? Instead of `<VirtualHost *:443>`. I tried the syntax check but it says okay.

But I can't restart the apache service. Because the service must keep going on.

Answer (score 0):

That `VirtualHost` block only affects clients who include a `host header` for `my.com`. The point of `VirtualHost` blocks is to have different configuration per domain (`host header`) such as:

- different web root directory
- different tls certificates
- different rewrites/exc.

the wildcard virtualhost will be a catch all (like default) block.

You can gracefully restart apache or reload it like so:

```
apachectl -k graceful
```

see this: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/stopping.html